# pgAdmin 4 cannot detect PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm facing an issue with pgAdmin 4 where it can't detect the PostgreSQL installation on my Mac operating system. When I run pgAdmin 4 it doesn't ask for a root password and doesn't load the PostgreSQL connection. Even other graphical editors such as DBeaver cannot detect the connection. I tried installing PostgreSQL via brew command, but that didn't solve the problem. I suspected a conflict between multiple installations, so I deleted all versions using uninstall and checked with the brew list that there was nothing left. However, after reinstalling the problem persisted and pgAdmin still cannot detect PostgreSQL.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem and get pgAdmin 4 to recognize PostgreSQL on macOS Monterey?

Comment: The PostgreSQL server is running? And the command line tool psql can connect to this server?

Comment: I don't think that pgAdmin "recognizes" PostgreSQL. You have to create a server connection and enter the correct connection information.

Comment: As a general rule clients don't automatically detect a server. It is fairly common that a client is installed on a machine that does not have a database server on it. In that case the connection could be to a database anywhere in the world. Even if there is a local install of a server, there maybe many instances of the server running with different authentications. Having a client start and try to blindly connect would be confusing. It is up to the user to decide to what server they want to connect and provide the correct information to the client.